# How does "community" work?

Tags: discussion, community-user

How did [community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) know to lock and delete [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14880/732) for example.

Moreover, it doesn't offer an undelete button (not that I would want to undelete it) and *seems* to have taken off a lot of points.

How does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, I (a ♦ mod at the time) flagged the post as offensive. I thought that this would delete the post in my name, but, no, it deleted (and, curiously, locked) the post in Community's name. In any event, whenever a mod deletes a post, it can't be undeleted by the community's vote (though it can be undeleted by any mod).

I don't know the complete list of actions Community takes credit for. One, as we see, is deletion of mod-flagged posts. Another is posting community-wiki posts (it owns the posts for purposes of accumulation of reputation). Another is, I think, downvoting deleted posts (it owns the downvote so the actual downvoter doesn't get debited reputation). Another is suggesting edits actually suggested by anonymous users. There are probably other things.

Comment: As long as you're here (ie and not in chat)...
@msh210 I'd be curious to hear more about to what extent you felt the comment thread here: judaism.stackexchange.com/… was off topic so I can avoid diverging too much in the future

Comment: now 1. It isn't locked and 2. It is "undeletable". How did that happen? How can someone undelete it if a mod deleted it?

Comment: @ShmuelBrill, 1, I unlocked it, and, 2, beats me. Maybe you can vote to undelete it but the votes won't take effect, or maybe I'm wrong that a mod deletion can't be reversed by the community, or maybe a mod deletion can't be but a Community deletion due to a mod's flagging can be.